# calculate binary to decimal manually

Tags: php, binary, decimal

assuming I have a function to manually calculate decimal from binary number
*up to four characters(binary)
*assuming you can only input 0 and 1 character

below code works perfectly

```
function bin_to_dec($bin) {
$bin = str_split($bin);
$bin = array_reverse($bin);

$i = 0;
$dec = 0;
foreach($bin as $values) {
    $ans = $values * pow(2, $i);
    $dec += $ans;
    $i++;
}

return $dec;
```

}

```
$bin = 1010 //4
$bin = 1 //1
$bin = 0 //0
```

assuming if you cannot use function strrev(), str_split(), array_reverse(), how would you convert binary to decimal manually?

Comment: `$length = strlen($bin); for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { $offset = $length - $i - 1; $values = $bin{$offset}; // .... rest of your loop code here }`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for the reply! your code helped me alot! my final code is
    $length = strlen($bin);
    $dec = 0;

    //ver.1
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $offset = $length - $i - 1;
        $values = $bin[$offset];

        $ans = $values * pow(2, $i);
        $dec += $ans;
}

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry my reply is hard to read, indent and newline does not seem to work in comment. but here is my ver.2 of code if ever substr() function is supported in project.
    $length = strlen($bin);
    $dec = 0;

    for($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
        $values = substr($bin, -$i, 1);
        $ans = $values * pow(2, $i-1);
        $dec += $ans;
    }

but I still prefer the version one since it does not depend much on php native functions so it will be more compatible on different ver. of php if functions does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you tried the built-in [bindec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) function ?

```
var_dump(bindec(1010)); // int(10)
var_dump(bindec(1)); // int(1)
var_dump(bindec(101010)); // int(45)
```

Beware though, this function is meant to be used with strings and can give strange results for ints beginning with `0` :

```
var_dump(bindec(0101)); // int(0)
var_dump(bindec("0101")); // int(5)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, sorry my question was not clear enough, I wanted to calculate binary to decimal manually so I did not want to use native php function like bindec().

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php

```
Example bindec() example

<?php
echo bindec('110011') . "\n";
echo bindec('000110011') . "\n";

echo bindec('111');
?>
The above example will output:

51
51
7
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, sorry my question was not clear enough, I wanted to calculate binary to decimal manually so I did not want to use native php function like bindec().

Comment: @ha_ryu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741587/how-to-convert-binary-to-decimal-without-using-php-native-functions

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it still uses php native functions, explode();
str_replace();
count();
chr(); :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `bindec()` function.

```
$ret_val = bindec("10001101");
```

this is one simple way,otherwise you can use...

```
    <?php
function strev($y)
{
for ($x = strlen($y)-1; $x>=0; $x--) {
       $y .= $y[$x];
       $y[$x] = NULL;
}
return $y;
}
function bintodec($str){
    $dec=0;
    $nstr=$str;
    $nstr=strev($nstr);
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
        $val = ($nstr%pow(10,strlen($nstr)-1)) * pow(2, $i);
        $dec += $val;
        $nstr=floor($nstr/10);
    }
    return $dec;
}
echo bintodec("1111010");
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! I tried your code but it seems your function bintodec() returns 0 all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to solve this for a student.

1. Split the string representation into digits
2. Reverse the digits
3. Initiate our result
4. Iterate over all the digits, adding 2 in the power of the index if the digit is a 1

Using the fact that each digit in binary adds 2 in the power of the digits index to the result.

Binary 11 is equal to 2^0 + 2^1 = 3

```
function binaryToDecimal($str) {
    $digits = str_split($str);
    $reversed = array_reverse($digits);
    $res = 0;

    for($x=0; $x < count($reversed); $x++) {
        if($reversed[$x] == 1) {
            $res += pow(2, $x);
        }
    }

    return $res;
}
```